# Redirect rule to remove query string from URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Have been trying to write a redirect rule with query string but did not succeed.

I have the URL `example.com/blog/?page=1` or `example.com/blog/?hello`, so it does not really matter what goes in the query string. How do I write a Redirect rule, so that it cuts the query string and redirects to the URL before the query string. For example, both of those URLs have to redirect to `example.com/blog/` so that URL does not contain any query string.

I was trying
`RewriteRule ^blog/?$ blog/ [R=301,L,NE]` but got redirected to 404 page.

Also tried
`RewriteRule ^blog/?$ /blog/ [R=301,L,NE]` and got the message that page is not working, 'URL' redirected you too many times.

BTW, technology I am using is Gatsby with htaccess plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the query string you first need to check that there is a query string to remove, otherwise, it should do nothing.

For example, to remove the query string from `/blog/?<query-string>` you would do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^(blog)/?$ /$1/ [QSD,R=302,L]
```

This matches the URL-path `blog/` (trailing slash optional) and redirects to `/blog/` (with a trailing slash). Your example URL includes the trailing slash, but your regex appears to suggest the trailing slash is optional?

The preceding *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) checks the `QUERY_STRING` server variable to make sure this is non-empty (ie. it matches a single character, denoted by the dot).

The `$1` backreference in the *substitution* string contains the value from the captured group in the preceding `RewriteRule` *pattern*. ie. "blog" in this example. This simply saves repetition. You could just as easily write `RewriteRule ^blog/?$ /blog/  [QSD,R,L]` instead.

The `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag removes the original query string from the redirected response, otherwise, this would be passed through by default (which would create a redirect-loop).

If the request does not contain a query string then this rule does nothing (since the *condition* will fail).

If this is intended to be permanent then change the 302 (temporary) redirect to 301 (permanent), but only once you have confirmed this works as intended. 301s are cached persistently by the browser so can make testing problematic.

---

**A look at your existing rules:**

> was trying `RewriteRule ^blog/?$ blog/ [R=301,L,NE]` but got redirected to 404 page.

By default, the relative *substitution* string (ie. `blog/`) is seen as relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file and this "directory-prefix" is then prefixed back to the relative URL, so this will (by default) result in a malformed redirect of the form `https://example.com/path/to/public_html/blog/`.

> Also tried `RewriteRule ^blog/?$ /blog/ [R=301,L,NE]` and got message that page is not working, 'url' redirected you too many times.

This is not checking for (or removing) the query string so this is basically just redirecting to itself - an endless redirect-loop.

---

#### Remove *any* query string from *any* URL

> What rule do i write, to remove query string from any URL.

Modify the `RewriteRule` *pattern* to match any URL and redirect to the same. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [QSD,R=302,L]
```

This needs to go at the top of the *root* `.htaccess` file before any existing rewrites.

If the `.htaccess` file is in a subdirectory (not the root) then you will need to do something like the following instead, since the `$1` backreference (as used above) won't contain the complete root-relative URL-path.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,R=302,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped.
Is there another rule to remove completely query strings from any url. I am using Gatsby, which is static site generator, so i do not have any query params. But my SEO shows that some pages where followed by bots with query string. What rule do i write, to remove query string from any url.

Comment: @YuriiKovalchuk I've updated my answer with a rule to remove the query string from any URL.

Comment: Thank you for answering, it did really help. Best regards!